# Start a 64bit app from a 32bit app?

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit, visual-c++

Under 64bit Windows 7, I want to start a 64bit executable(myapp64.exe) from a 32bit executable(myapp32.exe). Can I use CreateProcess, ShellExecute or ShellExecuteEx functions in myapp32.exe to do this? Will be there any problems or limitations?

I use Visual C++ 2008 to write both myapp32.exe and myapp64.exe.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine, as if the target were 32 bit too.  The 64 bit process will be completely separate from the 32 bit one (naturally) so its bitness doesn't really make any difference.

Problems might start to arise if you try to communicate with the 64 bit process without taking that into account.

Comment: "Completely separate" isn't entirely true, you do have inherited handles and environment variables. But those work fine across 32/64 bits processes.